# How to use a cloned Git repo as a "master" and remain in sync with a remote Git repo at a client site?

Tags: git, reference, repository, clone

I've have a local version of Stash running and all the local developers have access to it.  I am having a little difficulty wrapping my mind how to use it to work with a client's project.

I need to be able to clone my client's git repo (push it into Stash) as a reference repo.  All dev work from all my local devs will be done against that reference repo.  I want to make all the commits against that reference repo, and once all the changes have passed QA, only then push the final code back to the client.  For all intents and purposes, the client will not be getting all the day-to-day commits, only the final product.

What I am looking to do, and do not know if it is feasible, is to clone the client's repo locally, and make that a new origin for all the local developers.  Once all the work is complete, I only want to push the final commit up to the client (not all the intermediate commits).  To make things a little more complex, instead of using my local cloned repo as the origin for the developers, I want to push my cloned repo into my local Stash server and have that be the origin.

Moving the client's repo into Stash is easy (I can just log in, clone the repo, and push it into Stash).  What I do not know how to do is how to keep it sync'ed with the client.  ie: if the client makes changes, I want to pull those changes in.  Does it always have to remain a two-part process (ie: pull changes, rebase, and push)?  Do I have to do this in two different work paths (ie: one for my actual dev work, and one to do the pull/rebase/push)?  Is there any automated way of doing something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Eric, 
You should modify your approach to using Git in the way that it's meant to be used: have everyone work with their own git AND the remote.  Do not complicate the process by adding these QA restrictions and an responsibility a developer with the ultimate responsibility to push things up to remote, as this will only bog things down.  Learn about git tagging and branching, and have QA become comfortable with it too.  In this way, builds can be stamped ready for QA, developers can work off branches which will not impact head - until it's ready to do so - and most importantly, you won't be the bottleneck overseeing the push to remote.

A very good read on the subject is http://pragprog.com/book/tsgit/pragmatic-version-control-using-git

Comment: I understand, but there are a few restrictions.  1) The only access to the client Git repo is via a single VPN login that I am not allow to share.  Additionally, I do not want the local devs committing their work to the client's repo for a bunch of internal reasons.  I could theoretically pull a local copy on my machine and have all local devs clone from my machine and use theirs locally and push changes to each other and my own, but figured it would be easier with a central copy in Stash than rely on me being around to push changes to.